# Simple Question. How to convert python list to successfully use it in sqlite query

Tags: python, list, sqlite, cs50

I am trying to put test1 list into db query where :count is. Problem is it should be working fine as if I were to put WHERE id in (1, 2), but using my code it is not. Fix needed, will appreciate any teaching. I am new to programming.

```
from cs50 import SQL

db = SQL("sqlite:///database.db")
test2 = [1, 2]
test3 = str(test2).strip('[]')
print(test3)
dbcounted = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (:count);', count = test3)
print(dbcounted)
```

Comment: Any luck if you change it to:
`ex_str = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (' + test3 + ');'`
`dbcounted = db.execute(ex_str)`

Comment: That worked, thanks. I wonder why it didn't work before.

Comment: perhaps there is problem in the (:count) syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the [CS50 documentation](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/python/#cs50.SQL) it looks like it expects an array instead of a string.
So this gives you two options:

Assemble a full string and pass it:

```
from cs50 import SQL

db = SQL("sqlite:///database.db")
test2 = [1, 2]
ex_str = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (' + str(test2).strip('[]') + ');'
print(ex_str)
dbcounted = db.execute(ex_str)
print(dbcounted)
```

Or you can pass count as an array as expected by the function call:

```
from cs50 import SQL

db = SQL("sqlite:///database.db")
test2 = [1, 2]
dbcounted = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in (:count);', count = test2)
print(dbcounted)
```

Comment: First one works. The second option looked appealing to me I tried it, didn't work for some reason.

Comment: dbcounted = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (?);', test2) returns 0 rows so does dbcounted = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (:count);', count = test1)

Comment: What about `dbcounted = db.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (:count);', count = [1, 2])`?
If that doesn't work then you should unmark this as answered and someone might have further insight :)

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Well kudos for the first option that works. And most of all thank you for reaching out and doing your best to help. :)))